# Camel routes not getting resolved in xml file

Tags: java, apache-camel, java-11, spring5

I am upgrading from Java 8 to Java 11.
Even Spring version used earlier was 4.x now I have upgraded to Spring 5.x

I am using camel for routes

My camel context file is as follows

```
 <bean id="samplePriceBean"
    class="com.abc.SamplePriceBean">
    <constructor-arg index="0"
        ref="route1" />
        <constructor-arg index="1"
        ref="route2" />
    <constructor-arg index="2"
        ref="myCamelContext" />
    <constructor-arg index="3" value="route1" />
    <constructor-arg index="4" value="route1" />
</bean>
<camelContext id="myCamelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="listRoute" autoStartup="false">
        <from
            uri="file:{{abc.list}}?noop=true&amp;" />
        <to uri="direct:route1"
            id="route1" />
    </route>
    <route id="readRoute" autoStartup="false">
        <from
            uri="file:{{abc.read}}?noop=true&amp;" />
        <to uri="direct:route2"
            id="route2" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Now when I run the application error in console as follows

```
Error creating bean with name 'samplePriceBean' defined in class path resource [app-camel.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'route1' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'route1' available
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:787)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:226)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
```

The application is unable to resolve the routes defined in camel context

I am using  JDk 11 , SPring 5.x, Apache camel 3.0.0

Comment: Was this example workable before upgrading ? Where u define spring beans with id "route1" or "route2" ?

Comment: Yes it was working then

Answer (score 1):

Okay so this is really wrong from the beginning too

The `<route>` is for defining routes, and routes are not exposed as spring bean which spring dependency injection can use/lookup. Only `<camelContext>` is intended for that, as its `CamelContext`.

In your `SamplePriceBean` you can change its constructor to not take in route1 and route2 as refs, but you can just use the API from `CamelContext` to lookup these routes via `CamelContext` API (not spring bean ids).

Answer (score 0):

Camel 2.x does NOT support Java 11. You should use Camel 3 for Java 11 support.

Comment: I have even tried with version3.0.0 , but same issue